# 1-point compactification of long line (long circle)?

Tags: general-topology, compactification

The long line is locally compact and Hausdorff so it has a 1-point compactification. What can be said about it? Is it anything new? Searching internet for "long circle" returns no results, which seems strange since this seems like a pretty simple space to consider.

Comment: The one-point compactification of the closed long ray, called the extended long ray and the *two* points compactification of the long line, called the extended long line, are common spaces, but I've never seen the one-point compactification of the long line being called with a particular name. All of those spaces are somewhat less well behaved than the long ray/line: they are not topological manifolds (where I'm not asking for manifolds to be separable to count the long ray/line as manifolds)

Comment: How do you define the "long line"? There are several versions... Have you looked [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology))?

Comment: For a lot of related results involving the long line, see [*Various smoothings of the long line and their tangent bundles*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/000187089290027I) by Peter J. Nyikos. (FYI, I had a 2-semester course from him in the 1980s in which we pretty much covered all of Willard's text.)

Comment: Not sure if I would call that particular 1 point compactification space "simple". For example, that one point does not have a countable neighborhood basis.

Comment: How exactly did you search the internet for "long circle"?  https://www.google.com/search?q=%22long+circle%22+topology finds several relevant results...

Comment: @EricWofsey With duckduckgo and with google in my country neither returns relevant results for some reason. your google.com finds some, weirdly.